# How to stream a video using Play Framework and videojs?

Tags: java, playframework, video-streaming, playframework-1.x

Relating to [Streaming video in play framework using videojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264416/streaming-video-in-play-framework-using-videojs) I'd like to know the best way to stream a video using a Play controller.

I store my videos on the filesystem, and since not every user is allowed to watch every video, I want to restrict access using a controller. So my question is, how can I stream a video from within the controller to the client (running videojs)?

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Play are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 1.2.5 RC3 right now.

Comment: Sorry all I can is to redirect you to the [docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous#HTTPresponsestreaming). I had to ask about version for proper tagging

Comment: BTW it's seems that in Play 2.0 it would be just easier task, but I didn't find similar sample for P1

Comment: Thank you for your help - just switched to Play 2.0.1 right now...

Answer (score 0):

your video is a static content like an image or a .css file. you can use any webserver to serve this content.

if you want control the access there are many techniques. you can create a controller who validate the request, open the video and write bytes in the response. I never try this, for me is much more interesting generate a security token and serve the file over a apache or nginx who use some security plugin.

but if you think in something different than progressive download (like http live streaming or rtmp, rtsp, etc) you need a video server like wowza, flash media server or red5. you can use the same strategy of tokens

Comment: I guess rendering the video isn't the hardest part after all - any ideas on how I can embedd the video on the client-side? It seems that videojs uses publicly accessible paths, so do you have any idea on how to use it with a particular bytestream? thx!

Comment: In my opinion, you can use javascript to embed a flash and/or html5 and server side you can create a component who generate this code. It helps?

Comment: Ok, I assume I have to figure out, how I can do this with videojs - thank you for your help!